# Why is the type of value property of <input /> is not string?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I wrote the component below, using create-react-app with `--template typescript` options. It made the react SPA with Typescript.

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function Info() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [nickname, setNickname] = useState('');

  function onChangeName(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    setName(e.target.value);
  }

  function onChangeNickname(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    setNickname(e.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <input value={name} onChange={onChangeName} />
        <input value={nickname} onChange={onChangeNickname} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Info;
```

However, my editor(VS Code) gives an error about the type of `value` property in `<input />`.(Line 18, 19). It says `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number & (string | number | readonly string[] | undefined)'. [TS2322]`. Despite errors, it works well. But I can't understand the meaning of this message.

TS2322 is an error that occurred when using a not assignable typed value. According to the [`HTMLInputElement` Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement), `value` of input element is `string`. But my editor says `value` is not string type.

Why does `value` use `number & (string | number | readonly string[] | undefined)` in Typescript instead of `string` just like the MDN explains? and is there any way to fix it such as redeclaring the type of `value`?

Comment: It's important to note that the input mark-up in this case (`<input />`) is not HTML but JSX/TSX, which is intentionally very similar, but not identical behind the scenes. So the MDN documentation for HTML inputs may not always be relevant.

Comment: @DBS I understand the jsx is the markup for react elements, so it's not always same as HTML elements(such as tag closing, reserved name, etc.). However, I still can't understand the why 'value' propety works different, beacuse [document about jsx](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html) doesn't mention about type differences of `value` property.

Comment: I can't reproduce it (https://codesandbox.io/s/strongly-typed-react-events-inline-forked-58h66) can you make a sandbox?

Comment: [TypeScript's HTMLInputElement documentation](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/interfaces/_node_modules_typedoc_node_modules_typescript_lib_lib_dom_d_.htmlinputelement.html#value) confirms that `value` should indeed be of type `string`.  Reproduction would definitely help...

Comment: The error says line 31, 32. Your example does not have line 31, 32. Can you confirm if line 31, 32 are indeed the two `<input />`?

Comment: @yqlim It's line 18 and 19. I fixed it in question too

Comment: @yqlim https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-dust-kp4ui-kp4ui Here you are. But I can't reproduce it in code sandbox. I think it's problem of vs code or ide problem